# Need a way to close browser instance through truclient

Tags: loadrunner, truclient

While replaying the script in truclient during a transaction a new instance of browser opens, and due to this rest all transactions are failing. Is there a way to close the new browser instance so as to continue the script replay using truclient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you recorded the script and closed the new window during recording you should have a step that closes the window. The step should have title similar to "Close Tab active tab".

If you don't have this step you can add it manually from the toolbox after the step that causes the popup window to appear.
- In the toolbox select "Generic Browser Action" and drag it onto the script in the correct place. Then open the "step" dropdown and select "Close Tab" in the Action combo selector.

Alternatively you can try to create a global event handler.
- In the main toolbar (at the top of the script) click "Event Handler Editor", in the opened window add a new handler with the + sign (top left). Select the "event can be triggered during the entire script" checkbox and in the "type" select dialog.
Event type should be "Dialog Opened".

I hope one of these two solution will solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this option.

Answer (score 0):

Does your technology stack mandate the use of TruClient?  If not, have you considered the benefits of a straight HTML script?